# I would like my page editor to be sorted by date created, or updated, instead of in Alpha order, is this possible?

Tags: pages, sort, order

When looking at my "All Pages" they are listed in Alpha order, and I have to scroll through to find what I am updating. Is there a way to have a preference setting that it be sorted by date, without having to tell it every time to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to All pages, and see up in the right courner you can see Screen Options.

> [image]

You can set how many pages you want to have per page. Then wordpress will give you all the pages on one page. Then you can use CTRL + F or Mac I think it is Cmd + F, use that to search the page you are looking for.

Also you can sort it by date, by clicking on 'Title' or 'Date' to sort them:

> [image]